# Suggestions on how to find a valid thesis topic

Tags: phd, thesis

I am in my third year of PhD in Finance program, and I still haven't found a topic yet. I almost got burned out searching for topics. Stuff that I can think of are either trivial or have been done by the others before. Recently, I start feeling overwhelmed and self-doubting.

Coming from an eingeering background, I used to solve problems, but not really good at asking problems. I am in need of some plan to overcome this, or else I will probably quit the problem for good.

Comment: Did you talk to your advisor about it? If so, what did he/she suggest?

Comment: Those feelings are normal. I also expect your advisor will be helpful in identifying paths forward.

Comment: Vote to close as "unclear what you're asking" because I don't see a question here.

Comment: You don't mention your advisor at all. Finding a research topic is a task where you rely heavily on their expertise. Usually, you should decide on a topic early on, at least during your first year. If that hasn't happened, I'd suspect something is amiss in your relationship to your advisor.

Answer (score 2):

Coming up with a proper, well-formed, sane, attackable research problem is challenging and part of the job of a researcher. It isn't always easy.

Elements of a plan for you:

**Talk to your advisor/supervisor**

As others have mentioned as comments, you haven't indicated what your advisor has said to you or what guidance he or she has offered in finding a topic. What has he or she said/done/advised?

**Talk to your final class teachers**

Presumably over the previous three years you have been taking classes in your subject field. If this is true, and since your institution is a PhD-granting one, the teaching at this level should be research-informed. This means that the people teaching the subject material at graduate level should know what the limits of knowledge are in the field, and where there may be interesting questions to ask. Note --- they may not know what the questions are themselves (that's part of your job) but they should have some ideas where interesting work might be done.

**Talk to your peer group**

Who is in the same or similar field as you and doing research? Bounce ideas off them.

**Get to a conference/workshop/summer school**

If there's little to be gained in asking people around you (which is unlikely), see what summer schools are offered in your subject area and proceed as above: ask lecturers there what are the interesting areas in which to work. Ditto conferences --- whose work is interesting to you? Go talk to them. Find where your interests or skill sets overlap with what they consider areas of interesting opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

Read more articles! You must gather a critical mass of information.

You select some relevant topic to your field, then collect and critically analyze related background information. In other words, read tons of articles. Don't force an idea, instead you will eventually reach a critical mass of information. Things will fit together and it will look shimmery in your mind's eye. All of a sudden the critical mass becomes your idea.

The beautiful thing about this approach is that depends on the work of those around us/in our field. As well it should! Speaking for myself, before I learned this technique, I was quite arrogant to think I could just come up with a brilliant and fresh idea on my own. We're in graduate programs for a reason!

You got this! Discovery is hard because what you're looking for doesn't exist yet, self doubt is the totally appropriate reaction to that. ... go read a bunch of papers and good luck!